# C++ Не работает сравнение строк через if

Tags: c++, строки

Код:

```
char *CPFC = TEXT("C:\\Users\\Vasja-PC\\source\\repos\\Test\\Release\\Test.exe");
char CFP[128];
GetModuleFileName(NULL, CFP, 128);
if (CFP == CPFC) printf("Good!");
```

При данном сравнение сообщения `Good!` я не получаю, хотя при попытке сравнить 2 строки прямо в `if` то данное сообщение выводится. Это проблема точно не связана с неравенством строк, так как я вывел обе строки и они были полностью идентичны.

Comment: Во-первых, нуль-терминированные строки в С и С++ не сравниваются и никогда не сравнивались оператором `==`. `if` здесь ни при чем. Во-вторых, если тип строки у вас прошит жестко - массив `char`, то что здесь делает макро `TEXT`? С какой целью вы использовали этот `TEXT`?

Comment: А как тогда их сравнить?

Comment: `strcmp` всегда было.

Answer (score 2):

Сравнение строк в C++:

```
if (strcmp(CFP, CFPC) == 0)
```

**Внимание**:

При неподходящем использовании результата сравнения как булевого значения, т.е. в форме `if (strcmp(CFP, CFPC))` (без сравнения с нулем), возникнет путаница, потому что когда строки идентичны, *результат функции `strcmp()` будет `0`, что интерпретируется как **неправда** и код в ветви `if` не выполнится.*

Comment: Результат функции `strcmp` - это не "правда/неправда", а многозначное целочисленное значение. Поэтому использование `strcmp` (включая популярный уродливый антипаттерн `!strcmp`) без явного сравнения - дурная практика.

Comment: @AnT -  Я писал `0` - неправда только в скобках.

Comment: @MarianD, `strcmp` возвращает не булевое значение (0 или 1), а -1, 0, +1 в зависимости от того, меньше левая строка правой, равна или больше (меньше-больше - в смысле [лексикографического порядка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Лексикографический_порядок)). "Неправда" тут вообще ни при чем.

Comment: @insolor - Смотри мой прежний комментарий. В контексте моего ответа результат в частности `правда` или `неправда`.

Comment: @MarianD, что прежний, что нынешний - это набор малосвязанных слов. `strcmp` не возвращает правду-неправду, хоть в скобках, хоть без.