# strcpy_s вызывает ошибку

Tags: c++

```
struct disciplines {
    char discipline[20];
};
struct students {
    char group[10];
    char discipline[20];
    char teacher[30];
    char name[30];
    int mark;
};
void showAverage(std::vector<students>& student, std::vector<disciplines>& disList) {
    disciplines str;
    for (int i = 0; i < student.size(); i++) {
        disciplines t1;
        strcpy_s(t1.discipline, student[i].discipline);
        for (int j = 0; j <= disList.size(); j++) {
            disciplines t2;
            strcpy_s(t2.discipline, disList[i].discipline);
            if (t1.discipline == t2.discipline) break;
            else{ 
                strcpy_s(str.discipline, student[i].discipline);
                disList.push_back(str); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Пытаясь скопировать поле из одного вектора в другой вызывает ошибку"Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x0F64ED76 (ucrtbased.dll) в Проект.exe: Недопустимый параметр был передан функции, для которой недопустимые параметры вызывают неустранимую ошибку."
Срабатывает ошибка в строке

```
strcpy_s(t2.discipline, disList[i].discipline);
```

Поля являются массивами char. Первый такой же вызов отрабатывает нормально. В чем проблема и как ее решить?

Comment: Структуру, или класс `disciplines` добавьте в вопрос, ничего так не понять, что за поле `discipline`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Доступ в массив `disList` почему-то делается по индексу `i`, который лежит в диапазоне индексов массива `student`. Почему? Эти массивы как-то связаны?
- Тело цикла по `j` никак не зависит от `j` и индекс `j` более нигде вообще не используется. Возможно индекс `j` предназначался для доступа в массива `disList`?
- Но тогда почему условие во втором цикле использует `<=`

  ```
  for (int j = 0; j <= disList.size(); j++) {
  ```

  Доступ в `disList` по такому индексу вызовет вылет за пределы массива.
- Бессмысленное сравнение ([1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/926999/c-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0-char), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/718447/c-%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-if), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/759365/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-if-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B))

  ```
  if (t1.discipline == t2.discipline)
  ```

  Это условие всегда ложно. Следовательно на каждой итерации цикла по `j` делается `disList.push_back(str);`. Но так `j` никогда не сможет догнать `disList.size()`!